# Why is this erroring out?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

Here is my JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('testButton').onclick = function(){
  var tableResult = makeHTMLMatchesTable(fetchMatches());
  var matches = document.getElementById('matches')
  matches.parentNode.insertBefore(matches, tableResult);
}
```

I am trying to get this function to insert some HTML but I get the error: `NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.`

I don't really understand this error, I have tried putting in different arguments but it still keeps complaining about the child. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the order of the [`.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) arguments backwards. It should be:

```
parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode);
```

So in your specific case if you're trying to insert `tableResult` before `matches` then change it to:

```
matches.parentNode.insertBefore(tableResult, matches);
```